# Android Studio (Beta) 0.8.14 - unable to Launch Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-studio

just signed up to this site hoping that someone can help me out with this.

- I installed the most recent Android Studio a few days ago and can't
  figure out how to run the device emulator

.

- I chose to create the 'Default_Nexus_5' device and the device doesn't
  launch at all.

the run log has the following message:

```
D:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools\emulator.exe -avd Default_Nexus_5 -netspeed full -netdelay none
```

**The event log as the following message:**

```
11:23:26 PM Gradle build finished in 6 sec
11:24:40 PM Gradle build finished in 1 sec
```

Can someone tell me what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Use [Genymotion-THE FASTER ANDROID EMULATOR](http://www.genymotion.com/) instead,it actually takes less time than emulator takes to launch and run an application

Answer (score 1):

You might need to install Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager (HAXM) via `Tools -> Android-> SDK Manager`.

1. Download the Intel HAXM installer package for your platform from http://software.intel.com/en-us/android.
2. Install. During installation, it'll ask you for memory size - set this to 2GB or whatever you can afford.
3. When you create a new AVD in the AVD Manager, make sure that device's memory size doesn't exceed the number you set during the HAXM installer.

You shouldn't need to restart Android Studio after this. Just build, run and choose to launch the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

You can check in setting that there is an option saying that the minimum android level it needs to run. The problem is that the emulator'a level is lower than the complies version. You can check in setting. Forgot where

Comment: Thanks for replying user4277087,

The emulator's API version is 19 and the Android project I'm working on is set up on API 15. 

I changed it to API 15 and it seems to be working now, thank you!!

Comment: It worked by matching lowering the emulator's API version to match the project's API version thanks for your help!